Selenium IDE - Store text then use as alert
Here is my problem: I want to take text data from a test website (The price and its name). To do this I use Selenium IDE.
First, I take the text data using the "storeText" command, then I do an echo to see if my variable is populated and finally, I run a JS script to make an alert in my window.
However, I keep getting this message: Failed: TIME missing ) after argument list.
I know it comes from my variables, but I can't find a way to manage them and the Selenium IDE documentation is not very complete on this subject.
All I have just below:
This is my JS script :
alert("Le prix de " + ${name}.split(/bureau|jeu/)[1].split(" ").filter(Boolean).slice(0, 3).join(" ") + " est : " + ${price});

There is the .side file :
{
      "id": "07932a19-54e5-4bef-aaed-84f1e39fe1b5",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "storeText",
      "target": "css=.x-productListItem:nth-child(3) [data-automation=\"product-price\"] div div ",
      "targets": [],
      "value": "price"
    }, {
      "id": "4c84f025-021b-4478-8a12-b57e215df71b",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "storeText",
      "target": "css=.x-productListItem:nth-child(3) [data-automation=\"productItemName\"]",
      "targets": [],
      "value": "name"
    }, {
      "id": "f9b319ea-01c2-48c8-9e02-158ee20dad86",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "echo",
      "target": "${name}",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "a3678c8f-8010-400d-af1c-659608466dbe",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "executeScript",
      "target": "alert(\"Le prix de \" + ${name}.split(/bureau|jeu/)[1].split(\" \").filter(Boolean).slice(0, 3).join(\" \") + \" est : \" + ${price});",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }

And a screen shot of my IDE :

I have also seen the use of the "echo" command with target: javascript{alert("Hello world!")}, but it does not work as I want. This causes it to appear in the console.
